# ReactJS: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string while running a SSR application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

I'm trying to create a basic SSR react app.
Here is the complete list of steps I followed:

**Create a new React app using the create-react-app tool:**

```
npx create-react-app my-ssr-app
```

**Install the necessary dependencies:**

```
cd my-ssr-app
npm install --save express react react-dom react-router-dom react-helmet
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react babel-loader css-loader style-loader webpack webpack-cli webpack-node-externals
```

**Create a server.js file in the root directory of the app:**

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');
const { StaticRouter } = require('react-router-dom');
const { Helmet } = require('react-helmet');
const App = require('./src/App').default;

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  const context = {};
  const appMarkup = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
      <App />
    </StaticRouter>
  );
  const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();

  res.status(200).send(`
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        ${helmet.title.toString()}
        ${helmet.meta.toString()}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root">${appMarkup}</div>
        <script src="/static/js/main.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
  `);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

**Modify the package.json file to add a new build command:**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "react-scripts build && webpack --config webpack.server.js"
  }
}
```

**Create a webpack.server.js file in the root directory of the app:**

```
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './server.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'server.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
  },
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            '@babel/preset-react',
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
  },
};
```

**Run the build command:**

```
npm run build
```

**Start the server:**

```
node build/server.js
```

**However, after running the application on http://localhost:3000, I get the following error:**

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
    at renderElement (/Users/mmt10470/Documents/dev_per/my-ssr-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6047:9)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (/Users/mmt10470/Documents/dev_per/my-ssr-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6108:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (/Users/mmt10470/Documents/dev_per/my-ssr-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6080:14)
    at retryTask (/Users/mmt10470/Documents/dev_per/my-ssr-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6532:5)
    at performWork (/Users/mmt10470/Documents/dev_per/my-ssr-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6580:7)
    at /Users/mmt10470/Documents/dev_per/my-ssr-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6904:12
    at scheduleWork (/Users/mmt10470/Documents/dev_per/my-ssr-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:78:3)
    at startWork (/Users/mmt10470/Documents/dev_per/my-ssr-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6903:3)
    at renderToStringImpl (/Users/mmt10470/Documents/dev_per/my-ssr-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6977:3)
    at Object.renderToString (/Users/mmt10470/Documents/dev_per/my-ssr-app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:7065:10)
```

Can someone explain what is the issue here??

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, I will investigate and see if I can find a solution. Let's keep in touch

Comment: After some debugging, I'm 99% sure that the problem comes from StaticRouter (react-router-dom) - I don't have a solution yet, but are you using version 6 react-router-dom? Apparently with 5 there is no problem

Comment: Found it ! With V6 of react-router-dom you have to import StaticRouter like that : "import { StaticRouter } from "react-router-dom/server". Also remove "context=..." no more available in V6.

Comment: yeah that worked ... you can add an answer with the solution

Comment: have you successfully implemented SSR with your application? If so, would you have a source to share please? I'm currently in trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With react-router-dom V6 you have to import StaticRouter like that `import { StaticRouter } from "react-router-dom/server`. Also you have to remove `context=...` this one, is no more available in V6.